# Classes aren't being initialized properly in python

Tags: python, kivy

Trying to learn how to use Kivy (havn't ever programmed anything other than school work before) and i'm running into a bit of trouble.

My code is shown below.

The problem lies in my Ball class, when the app starts `BubblePop.SetupLevel()` is called and balls should be filled with instances of the Ball class. But somehow it's not working. So when `BobblePop.update()` is called i get a error on the `ball.draw()` line

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draw'


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
    ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
from random import random, randint
from kivy.core import window
#balls are what bounce around the screen. They turn into bubbles upon 
#colliding with a bubble.

def Ball(width,height):
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.x = randint(0,width)
        self.y = randint(0,height)
        self.colorRGB = [0,0,0]
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        self.ball_size = 20

    def draw(self):
        Ellipse(pos=(self.x,self.y), size = (self.ball_size,self.ball_size))


class Bubble(Widget):
    pass

class BubblePop(Widget):
    balls = []
    bubbles = []

    def SetupLevel(self,numballs):
        for x in xrange(numballs):
            ball = Ball(self.height,self.width)
            self.balls.append(ball)

    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        with self.canvas:
            r = random()
            g = random()
            b = random()
            Color(r,g,b)
            d = 80.
            self.bubbles.append([touch.x - d / 2,touch.y - d / 2,[r,g,b]])
            Ellipse(pos=(self.bubbles[-1][0], self.bubbles[-1][1]), size=(d, d))


    def update(self,dt):
        with self.canvas:
            self.canvas.clear()
            for ball in self.balls:
                ball.draw()

class BubbleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = BubblePop()
        game.SetupLevel(10)
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BubbleApp().run()
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Maybe because ball.draw () has no canvas?

Answer (score 2):

your Ball "class" looks weird. The way you defined it, it's not a class but a function. You have

```
def Ball(width,height):
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.x = randint(0,width)
        self.y = randint(0,height)
        self.colorRGB = [0,0,0]
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        self.ball_size = 20
```

where I think you would need something like

```
class Ball():
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        ...
```

Now, whenever you call `b = Ball(...)`, b will be `None` because your function never returns a value.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined a Ball class, you've defined a function called Ball.

The first line of the code itself should be:

```
class Ball(Widget):
```

(assuming Ball inherits from Widget like Bubble does).

Comment: oh wow, thanks soo much. Not sure how i've missed this after an hour looking it over.